# Fancybox doesnt work online

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

Im using the fancybox plugin for my bootstrap website, and everything works fine, on my localhost. When i publish my website online, the plugin stops working, and when i click the images it just opens on another side.

```
            <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Overwrite stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- Fancybox stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fancybox JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

                CONTENT HERE
                CONTENT HERE
                CONTENT HERE
                CONTENT HERE

         <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Logo fadeIn -->  
<script src="js/logo.js"></script>
 <!-- Swap content myWork -->  
<script src="js/swapcontent.js"></script>
 <!-- Scroll Animation -->  
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
 <!-- Contact me -->  
<script src="/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/contact_me.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you publish the site, does it keep your directory structure the same - ie is you js folder still relative to the html file?

Comment: Yes, the path remains the same

Comment: do you have any errors in the js console? (f12 and console tab in your browser)

Comment: Im using the inspector plugin for Chrome, and get no errors regarding the fancybox.js

Comment: do you have a link to your deployed site?

Comment: Chpo.dk Its the portfolio section

Comment: You have a js error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find validation info for 'Minlength'` may be causing the fancybox not to fire

Comment: looks to be to do with your text area - think you have a data validation message for the min length but no attribute setting the min length

Comment: "data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" <-- that was my problem. Thanks a lot Pete!!